# Oracle SQL MINUS on 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create an Oracle SQL query possibly using MINUS

```
Booking(BookID, MotelID, ClientID, Date)
Motel(MotelID, MotelName)
Client(ClientID, ClientName)
```

I can show the names of clients who have stayed at either motel (I think!!!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientName
FROM   (Client INNER JOIN Booking
ON     Client.ClientID = Booking.ClientID)
     INNER JOIN Motel
     ON Booking.MotelID = Motel.MotelID
WHERE (MotelName = 'MotelOne' OR MotelName='MotelTwo');
```

But I now need to show the clients who have stayed at MotelOne but NOT MotelTwo.

Very new to this, and trying to get my head around it so any help will be gratefully accepted!

Comment: What you need to do then, is think of it in terms of a list of client_id's who have made a booking at MotelOne, and a list of the clients who have made a booking at MotelTwo. Those separate queries can be combined with a minus to give a list of clients who made a booking at motelone without those who made a booking at moteltwo. does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has a MINUS operator --> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm
It returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second.

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname
  FROM booking b JOIN client c
    ON b.clientid = c.clientid JOIN motel m
    ON b.motelid = m.motelid
 WHERE m.motelname = 'MotelOne'
MINUS
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname
  FROM booking b JOIN client c
    ON b.clientid = c.clientid JOIN motel m
    ON b.motelid = m.motelid
 WHERE m.motelname = 'MotelTwo'
```

MINUS operator sorts rows and eliminates duplicates, so SELECT DISTINCT is not required.